# Временное прерывание работы скрипта

Tags: php

Например, мне нужно выполнить скрипт 1000 раз, т.е. он берет одну переменную, что-то с ней делает, берет вторую переменную и т.д.

Как сделать так, чтобы все происходило так:
Он берет одну переменную, что-то с ней делает, выдает результат работы с первой переменной, берет вторую переменную, что-то с ней делает, выдает результат работы со второй переменной и т.д.
Причем после выполнения работы со второй и последующими переменными, данные о ранних переменных бы не стирались.

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут видимо сессии нужны, а для выборки переменных, достаточно удобно использовать SPL. Скажем, вытянули переменную и засунули ее в стек обратно. Она опять попадает в очередь. Надеюсь я вас правильно понял.

$stack = new SplStack();

```
    $stack->push('1');
    $stack->push('2');
    $stack->push('3');

    echo $stack->pop()."\n"; // 3
    echo $stack->pop()."\n"; // 2
    echo $stack->pop()."\n"; // 1
```